# sorting programme on Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I've seen a following sorting programme on Ruby but I don't think I fully understand how it actually works:

```
def sort arr
    rec_sort arr, []  
end

def rec_sort unsorted, sorted

    if unsorted.length <= 0
        return sorted
    end
    smallest = unsorted.pop
    still_unsorted = []

    unsorted.each do |tested|
        if tested < smallest 
            still_unsorted.push smallest
            smallest = tested
        else 
            still_unsorted.push tested
        end
    end
    sorted.push smallest
    rec_sort still_unsorted, sorted
end

puts sort ["satoshi", "Bitcoin", "technology", "universe", "smell"]

=> Bitcoin
   satoshi
   smell
   technology
   universe
```

But when I change the first argument of the "rec_sort" method from "still_unsorted" (as indicated above) to "unsorted", the programme gives :

```
=> Bitcoin
   Bitcoin
   Bitcoin
   Bitcoin
   satoshi
```

I understand that the each loop selects the word "Bitcoin" first (because it would indeed come first when sorted), and "Bitcoin" would be put into the array "sorted". What I dont't quite understand is why there are several "Bitcoin" here, since it should have been excluded from the "unsorted" array in the first iteration of the each loop and, therefore, could not appear in the following iterations, making it impossible for "Bitcoin" to be in the "sorted" array several times.

Could you tell me what makes the two so different?
Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: as far as I understand its a recursive implementation of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). and for you confusion `unsorted` is not being modified except for the statement `unsorted.pop` but only is being replicated into the `still_unsorted` except for the smallest element in that array

Comment: you are aware that puts ["satoshi", "Bitcoin", "technology", "universe", "smell"].sort gives you what nou need ?, the sorting algorithm used in your example looks clumsy, if you are interested in sorting techniques I would look for another source

Answer (score 0):

The `still_unsorted` array has the `smallest` element removed, but the `unsorted` array only has its last element removed.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand its a recursive implementation of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). and for you confusion `unsorted` is not being modified except for the statement `unsorted.pop` but only is being replicated into the `still_unsorted` except for the smallest element in that array

I am dry running this on [3,1,2] for you

```
unsorted = [3,1,2]
sm = unsorted.pop # sm = 2 unsorted = [3,1]
still_unsorted = []
#after loop unsorted.each
# still_unsorted = [2,3]
# unsorted = [3,1]
# sm = 1
# sorted = [1]
```

do the next 2 iterations you'll understand what's happening